# Saving a calibrated route in QGIS for "future" use

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, linear-referencing

Can a Calibrated Vector (after using LRS) be saved with M values, so that the file does not have to be calibrated every time is used? We're currently working on State road data, and it has many records both on roads, a swell as the measure points. Is there a way that once the vectores have been calibrated, these can be saved so that we dont have to go through the process of calibrating every time we use it?

Comment: That's currently not implemented in the plugin, but shouldn't be very difficult to implement. Consider suggesting it as a new feature at https://github.com/blazek/lrs/issues/

Comment: @gcarrillo Please post your comment as an answer so we can upvote it and mark this thread as answered

Answer (score 2):

That's currently not implemented in the plugin, but shouldn't be very difficult to implement. Consider suggesting it as a new feature at http://github.com/blazek/lrs/issues